# Is this for loop in a physics tutorial completely superfluous?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, math

I am exploring code for a [particle physics simulation tutorial](https://github.com/matthias-research/pages/blob/master/tenMinutePhysics/18-flip.html#L509) and I cannot for the life of me understand what a line is doing:

```js
this.p.fill(0.0);
this.prevU.set(this.u);
this.prevV.set(this.v);

var n = this.fNumY;
var cp = this.density * this.h / dt;

for (var i = 0; i < this.fNumCells; i++) {
    var u = this.u[i];
    var v = this.v[i];
}
```

As far as I can see that for loop is not doing anything. The variables are declared, initialised but never used for anything it seems?

Comment: not only are they not doing anything (_technically_ they are function-scoped, so they persist after the for loop. And exist before it even starts, but they're not used anywhere else in the function). But also, this feels like highly legacy  code.  It claims to be (c) 2022 but in 2022 `var` had been replaced by `let` and `const` for quite a while, and ES2022 has _so many_ modern things that aren't used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is equivalent to `var u = this.u[this.fNumCells-1]; var v = this.v[this.fNumCells-1];`, and it does not look like those vars are used later.

Somebody probably just forgot to remove the unused code.